# Speech-to-text / Translation app recommendations?

Tags: speech-recognition, translation, speech-synthesis

Are there any good (preferably Windows or Android) apps that will do speech-to-text and also translate the text from English to Spanish or from Spanish to English.

I know they would not be perfect, but something that could be used as a starting point / notepad for interpreting.

I don't know if they are allowed, but such an app would be very useful in a courtroom or hospital room setting (places where interepretation often occurs, and accuracy is critical).

IOW, if a person says, "The rain in Spain falls mainly on the plain," I want to see:

```
[Heard English]: The rain in Spain falls mainly on the plain
[Translated Spanish]: La lluvia en España cae principalmente en la llanura
```

...or at least something like:

```
[Heard English]: The reign in Spain falls mainly on the plane
[Translated Spanish]: El reinado en España cae principalmente en el plano
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found Hintscribe.com. It's desktop app that transcribes speech to text system audio in real time and you can select any portion or whole transcription to prompt chat GPT about it.

It can translate, answers questions, summarize, whatever you want.